# functions does not have derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

$f(x)=|x-1|$. I know it is not analytic because $f'(1)$ doesn’t exist. But why doesn't it exist?

---

$f(x)=x^{\frac73}$. I know is not analytic because $f'''(0)$ doesn’t exist. But why doesn't it exist?

Comment: Hint: check left and right hand limits.

Answer (score 1):

Ill help you with the first one.

You want to investigate $f'(1)$. i.e $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}$ from both right and left.

From right we get
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h - 0}{h} = 1.
$$

From left we get

$$
\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{ - h - 0}{h} = -1
$$

Since $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} \not = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}$ we conclude that $f'(1)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a simpler function, like $y=x^2$, you can see that it changes *smoothly*. If you took any two points on the curve, and scooted them closer and closer and closer together, the slope at those points would approach being equal. The function has no sharp "bends".

The derivative is a function that describes the slope of a curve at a given point. What is the slope of a hard bend in the function? Well, there isn't really a slope—the function instantly changes directions.

This is the intuitive answer to the question. For a more rigorous solution, you could refer to the [limit definition of calculus](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx) and attempt to evaluate it at $x = 1$. You will see it break down.